# there is no error but ListView not showing up

Tags: android, android-listview

why my listView didn't show up.. what is wrong with my coding? the listView supposedly showing up the data from my database.. here is my coding... it didnt showing up any error.so i don't know where is the mistake.

Faculty.java

```
package com.example.prototype;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Faculty extends Activity {

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    // List view
    private ListView myListView;
    private DatabaseAdapter DbAdapter;


   /* // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;    
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;*/


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qs_faculty);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
        DbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        DbAdapter.open();

      //Clean all Customers
        DbAdapter.deleteAllCustomers();
        //Add some Customer data as a sample
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA1", "Pizza Hut", "1107 West Adams Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA2", "Pizza Hut", "1562 West Pico Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA3", "Pizza Hut", "718 South Los Angeles Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90014", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA4", "Pizza Hut", "2542 West Temple Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90026", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA5", "Pizza Hut", "4329 North Figueroa Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90065", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("PIZZA6", "Pizza Hut", "4351 South Central Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90011", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("SUB1", "Subway", "975 West Jefferson", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("SUB2", "Subway", "2805 South Figueroa Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("SUB3", "Subway", "198 South Vermont Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90004", null, null);
        DbAdapter.createLocation("SUB4", "Subway", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015", null, null);

         }    

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Because this activity has set launchMode="singleTop", the system calls this method
        // to deliver the intent if this activity is currently the foreground activity when
        // invoked again (when the user executes a search from this activity, we don't create
        // a new instance of this activity, so the system delivers the search intent here)
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, FacultyDetail.class);
            wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handles a search query
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            showResults(query);
        }
    }
        private void showResults(String query) {

            Cursor cursor = DbAdapter.searchCustomer((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));

            if (cursor == null) {
                // There are no results
                inputSearch.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
            } else {
                // Display the number of results
                int count = cursor.getCount();
                String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                        count, new Object[] {count, query});
                inputSearch.setText(countString);

                // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
                String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_ALAMAT,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_NOTEL,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_FAX,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_EMAIL,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TRANSPORT,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_LANDMARK,
                                               DatabaseAdapter.KEY_WEBSITE};

                // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.faculty_name,
                                        R.id.faculty_alamat,
                                        R.id. faculty_notel,
                                        R.id. faculty_fax,
                                        R.id. faculty_email,
                                        R.id. faculty_transport,
                                        R.id. faculty_landmark,
                                        R.id. faculty_website};

                // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
                SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                              R.layout.qs_faculty_detail, cursor, from, to);
                myListView.setAdapter(words);

             // Define the on-click listener for the list items
                myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FacultyDetail.class);
                        wordIntent.putExtra("KEY_ROWID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                      /*  Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id));
                        wordIntent.setData(data);*/
                        startActivity(wordIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
  }
```

FacultyDetail.java

```
package com.example.prototype;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FacultyDetail extends Activity {

        private TextView name;
        private TextView alamat;
        private TextView notel;
        private TextView fax;
        private TextView email;
        private TextView transport;
        private TextView landmark;
        private TextView website;
        private int placeId;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qs_faculty_detail);


        /*placeId = getIntent().getIntExtra("KEY_ROWID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.firstName, emp.lastName, emp.title, emp.officePhone, emp.cellPhone, emp.email, emp.managerId, mgr.firstName managerFirstName, mgr.lastName managerLastName FROM employee emp LEFT OUTER JOIN employee mgr ON emp.managerId = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+ placeId});*/

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_name);
            name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));

            alamat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_alamat);
            alamat.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            notel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_notel);
            notel.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("No_tel")));

            fax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_fax);
            fax.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Fax")));

            email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_email);
            email.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Email")));

            transport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_transport);
            transport.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Transport")));

            landmark = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_landmark);
            landmark.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Landmark")));

            website = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faculty_website);
            website.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Website")));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.faculty_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

DatabaseAdapter.java

```
package com.example.prototype;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_ALAMAT = "Alamat";
    public static final String KEY_NOTEL = "No_tel";
    public static final String KEY_FAX = "Fax";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String KEY_TRANSPORT = "Transport";
    public static final String KEY_LANDMARK = "Landmark";
    public static final String KEY_WEBSITE = "Website";
    public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "Category";

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AcademicLocation";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "UKM_Location";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Create a FTS3 Virtual Table for fast searches
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" +
        KEY_NAME + "," +
        KEY_ALAMAT + "," +
        KEY_NOTEL + "," +
        KEY_FAX + "," +
        KEY_EMAIL + "," +
        KEY_TRANSPORT + "," +
        KEY_LANDMARK + "," +
        KEY_WEBSITE + "," +
        KEY_CATEGORY + "," +
        " UNIQUE (" + KEY_NAME + "));";


    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }


    public long createLocation(String name, String alamat, String notel, String fax, String email, String transport, String landmark, String website, String category) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        String searchValue =     name + " " + 
                                alamat + " " + 
                                notel + " " + 
                                fax + " " + 
                                email + " " + 
                                transport+ " " + 
                                landmark+ " " + 
                                website+ " " + 
                                category;
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ALAMAT, alamat);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NOTEL, notel);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FAX, fax);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TRANSPORT, transport);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LANDMARK, landmark);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEBSITE, website);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);

        return mDb.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }


    public Cursor searchCustomer(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + KEY_NAME + "," + "," +
         " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
        " where " +  KEY_NAME + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
        Log.w(TAG, query);
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }


    public boolean deleteAllCustomers() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;

    }

}
```

please do help me solving this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there are some results with incoming query?

```
String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
showResults(query);
```

Instead of this :

```
if (cursor == null) {
   // There are no results
   inputSearch.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
}
```

try :

```
if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   // There are no results
   inputSearch.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your cursor contains some data (try to debug or get data from it). First of all you need to find out the reason of this bug.

Comment: If cursor isn't empty then there is something wrong with adapter initialization.